# How to update values via Procedure in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I've just learnt about creating procedure in Firebird.

I just want to know how and where I can put the updating code? I've read the syntax from this link [Firebird Update Insert Syntax](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html). But still no understand what it means.

Comment: You might want to describe in more details what you want to do. I'd also suggest you read the chapter [Procedural SQL (PSQL) Statements](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql.html) in the Firebird 2.5 language reference.

Answer (score 4):

> A stored procedure (SP) is a code module that can be called by the
>   client, by another stored procedure or by a trigger. Stored procedures
>   and triggers are written in Procedural SQL (PSQL). Most SQL statements
>   are also available in PSQL, sometimes with restrictions or extensions.
>   Notable exceptions are DDL and transaction control statements.
>
> Stored procedures can accept and return multiple parameters.

See: [firebirdsql.org -> `PROCEDURE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-procedure.html)

For example:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure UPDATE_TABLE (
    IID integer,
    INAME char(100))
as
 begin
  update or insert into table1(id,FNAME)
  values (:IID,:INAME);
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

This procedure will update or insert values into fields ID and FNAME on "Table1" using parameters "IID" and "INAME".

**Here field `id` is a primary key. So, matching is done against the primary key.**

Call :

```
execute procedure update_table(1000,'MyName');
```

Comment: Could you update your quote and link to one of the Firebird 2.5 language reference (instead of the Firebird 2.1 language reference update).

Comment: @ReneHoffmann the edited you did links to the Firebird 2.5 language reference update instead of the Firebird 2.5 language reference.

Comment: Done. Thank you @Mark. Strange, I can not find it in firebirdsql.org.

Comment: It is the second link on http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ ("[Firebird 2.5 Language Reference Beta 1 (English)](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25.html)"), where did you look?